# Method to adjust errorbars in seaborn regplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

**Background**
I am plotting my data using `sns.regplot` (seaborn 0.11.0, Python 3.8.5). I use the argument 'x_estimator' to plot the mean of each category shown on the x-axis, and for each point on the x-axis I have an errorbar which is bootstrapped using the `sns.regplot` arguments 'ci' and 'boot'.

Since this plot needs to have a specific dots per inch (DPI) of 800, I needed to readjust the scaling of the original plot to make sure the desired DPI was obtained.

**Problem**
Due to the rescaling, my errorbars appear to be rather 'wide'. I would like to make them less wide, and if it is possible, I would also like to add caps on the errorbars. I have included my code below using a randomly generated dataset. Running this code, one can see that the [plot that I obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J92B.jpg) has the correct DPI, but the errorbars are too wide.

**Edit for clarification**

I am fine with the confidence intervals (CI) in itself. My only worry is that the CIs are a bit too wide. This is probably some formatting issue. I already checked `line_kws` and `scatter_kws` but I can't find any formatting options for the CIs. My desired output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBDRq.jpg): the same bars, but not as 'heavy' as the original ones.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#%%

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy             as np
import pandas            as pd
import seaborn           as sns

from matplotlib import rcParams

#%%

# seaborn params
sns.set_style("ticks")
sns.set_context("paper")

# plotting params
rcParams['font.family']     = 'Times New Roman'
rcParams['axes.titlesize']  = 6
rcParams['axes.labelsize']  = 5
rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 5
rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 5

#%%

# some toy data into to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': np.random.normal(0, 1, (800,)), 
                   'X': np.repeat(range(1, 9), 100), 
                   'Condition': np.tile(["A", "B"], 400)}, 
                  index=range(800))

#%%
    
# make a subplot with 1 row and 2 columns
fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(1, 2,
                            sharex  = True, 
                            sharey  = True,
                            squeeze = True)

# A condition
g = sns.regplot(x           = "X", 
                y           = "Y", 
                data        = df.loc[df["Condition"] == "A"], 
                x_estimator = np.mean, 
                x_ci        = "ci", 
                ci          = 95,
                n_boot      = 5000,
                scatter_kws = {"s":15}, 
                line_kws    = {'lw': .75},
                color       = "darkgrey",
                ax          = ax_list[0])

# B condition
g = sns.regplot(x           = "X", 
                y           = "Y", 
                data        = df.loc[df["Condition"] == "B"], 
                x_estimator = np.mean, 
                x_ci        = "ci", 
                ci          = 95,
                n_boot      = 5000,
                scatter_kws = {"s":15}, 
                line_kws    = {'lw': .75},
                color       = "black",
                ax          = ax_list[1])

# figure parameters (left figure)
ax_list[0].set_title("A condition")   
ax_list[0].set_xticks(np.arange(1, 9))
ax_list[0].set_xlim(0.5, 8.5)
ax_list[0].set_xlabel("X")
ax_list[0].set_ylabel("Y")

# figure parameters (right figure)
ax_list[1].set_title("B condition")   
ax_list[1].set_xlabel("X")
ax_list[1].set_ylabel("Y")

# general title
fig.suptitle("Y ~ X", fontsize = 8) 

#%%

# set the size of the image
fig.set_size_inches(3, 2)

# play around until the figure is satisfactory (difficult due to high DPI)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.15, left=0.185, right=0.95, hspace=0.075,
                    wspace=0.2)

# save as tiff with defined DPI
plt.savefig(fname = "test.tiff", dpi = 800)

plt.close("all")
```

Comment: An idea is to multiply figure width and height with 4, use dpi=200, and then use an image manipulation program to modify the dpi to 800.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way of just altering the format of the CIs? I can use another program, but if everything can be done in Python without other software I would prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ci` parameters in `sns.regplot` to a lower value

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have added some extra clarification to my problem, along with my desired output. The problem is about how the CIs look, but I am fine with how far the CIs reach from each mean.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself and found a hacky solution.
It looks like keyword arguments for the confidence intervals (CI) are not yet exposed to the user (see [here](https://github.com/seaborn/seaborn/blob/d1c04f2c2c4dbd11ede016405b5ea51380e37f51/seaborn/regression.py#L398)). But we can see that it sets the CI line width to `1.75 * linewidth` from `mpl.rcParams`. So I think you can get what you want by hacking a matplotlib rcParams context manager.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# Insert other code from your question here
# to get your dataframe
df = ...

# Play around with this number until you get the desired line width
line_width_reduction = 0.5

linewidth = mpl.rcParams["lines.linewidth"]
with mpl.rc_context({"lines.linewidth": line_width_reduction * linewidth}):
    g = sns.regplot(
        x="X", 
        y="Y", 
        data=df.loc[df["Condition"] == "A"], 
        x_estimator=np.mean, 
        x_ci="ci", 
        ci=95,
        n_boot=5000,
        scatter_kws={"s":15}, 
        line_kws={'lw': .75},
        color="darkgrey",
        ax=ax_list[0]
    )
```